# If I'm reheating things in tins and I don't have enough oven space, can I stack them on top of each other?

Tags: reheating

I'm reheating a bunch of leftovers, all stored in aluminum tins. I don't have enough oven rack space to lay it all out flat. Can I stack the tins?

(Additionally, is it safe to leave on the paper/aluminum covers - the ones that are cardboard on one side and silver on the other?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as the containers can support eachother, it is likely safe to stack them. You biggest issue will be uneven reheating. Containers at the center are likely to remain cold. If you do stack them, insure that you occasionally rotate them. If possible, try to stack them in a way that allows for air flow around them. Stack layers at 90 degree angles.

The flash point of paper is about 450F so you should be fine with the covers.

Answer (score 1):

I use those all the time and it is safe to use the covers on the tin. If you want the top to brown or anything you will want to take it off near the end of the cook time.

As for stacking them... I haven't tried that as of yet but I would be hesitant to do this for two main reasons. The first is that they might get squished under the weight of the one on top. I know mine keeps it's shape when the food inside is frozen yet when it has been first filled with food or when I am taking it out of the oven it is 'bendable'. The second reason I would be hesitant is whether then tins in the centre would get enough heat. To combat this you would have to keep rotating it and the overall cook time would probably increase.